# Using login_generator in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, aptana3

Hello dear Programmers,

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 as an IDE and i installed the gem `login_generator-1.2.2` with

```
$ gem install login_generator
```

in command line.
My problem is that I want to use this gem now.

I want to generate a login like this:

[image]

The problem here is that the Aptana Studio 3 doesn't have the Generators tab and I don't know how to perform this command in the Terminal...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can add gem to your Gemfile, bundle it and then enter to project path and type "rails c" with command line. Then you can call methods as LoginGenerator::Methodxxx. Not sure what the gem does and it seems heavily undocumented :-(